# How can I setup an online server to constantly be executing my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, hosting, web-hosting

I have created a JavaScript program that I want to have running 24/7 on an online server. How do I setup a server to make that happen? I am using infinityfree.com as my host for now. At the moment I have setup an HTML file that loads my javascript when a user connect to the webpage, but that is not the behavior that I want.

Ideally I would like to be able to use this infinityfree server to host a very simple website, and have it also constantly running my Javascript code, whever a user is accessing the site or not. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I will be online to answer all questions or comments instantly for the next 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Use NodeJs : https://nodejs.org/

You can easly run js scripts with it.

My advice is to use docker to run and deploy a node server in just 2 minutes of time. After adapt you're script to never end. At the end, you Just need to find a cloudhoster.